# Do goto statements in C and assembly break locality of reference thereby decreasing performance?

Tags: c, assembly, goto

I wrote a program in C that selects random words from a book in txt file format and prints them out one by one using goto statements. When I run the program it takes about 2 to 3 minutes to start running.  Could it be that goto statements break locality of reference and drastically decrease performance?  Also does jmp in assembly act as goto breaking locality of reference as well?

Comment: Most likely, you have a I/O problem and/or an algorithmic complexity problem.

Comment: How do you print them out using goto statements?

Comment: You will need to explain what your program is doing in more detail. It's probably more down to algorithms than low-level details like that. If you're on \*nix, you could do `time ./your_program` to get a rough idea how much time is spent executing your code vs. doing e.g. disk I/O. (In the `time`output, *real* is the total amount of time your program takes, *user* the amount of CPU time spent in your code, and *sys* the amount of CPU time spent in the kernel. *real* being much higher than the total of those might indicate you're limited by disk I/O.)

Comment: @Ulfalizer I am not as much concerned with the performance of the program as with trying to understand if goto and jmp statements break locality of reference, but thanks for the suggestions on how to test I/O vs execution time I will check that as you suggested.

Comment: @Urler: All flow control constructs (`if`, `while`, `for`, `goto`, etc.) turn into (either conditional or unconditional) jumps at the machine code level, so it's impossible to make a blanket statement about `goto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question. Gotos might impair locality or might not, it depends on the case. But even when this holds, it is not necessarily bad. For this case, you need to post some code. Take a look at these 2 examples:

CASE 1:

```
for(int i = 0; i<SIZE ; i++){
   if( strcmp(words[i],"key")==0 )
    goto end;
}

end:
    printf("FOUND!\n");

return 1;
```

CASE 2:

```
int flag = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<SIZE ; i++){
   if( strcmp(words[i],"key")==0 )
    flag = 1;
}

end:
    if(flag) printf("FOUND!\n");
```

Of course that CASE 2 enjoys more locality than the first, but CASE 1 would be more efficient (i.e. it would take less time to run), except for the case where `"key"` is on the last position of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually all flow control results in some form of jump. Most only jump locally so will not break locality. If your program is taking minutes to start, you probably have it doing something like reading that (large?) text file before it does anything else. Try it with a small file and see how it runs then.